# Laravel's collection filter pass by reference not working

Tags: php, laravel-5, closures

can you please help me in using closures. I'm using laravel's collection filter to check unique emails. The code below should fill the `$unique_email` array inside the filter function. Is there's a problem on how i used the pass by reference? Thanks in advance.

```
    $unique_email = array();

    $users->filter(function ($user) use (&$unique_email) {
        if( !in_array(   $user->email , $unique_email  ) ) {
            return $unique_email[] = $user->email;              
        }
    });

    dd($unique_email); //returns empty array
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter must return boolean

```
$unique_email = array();

$users->filter(function ($user) use (&$unique_email) {
    if( !in_array(   $user->email , $unique_email  ) ) {
        $unique_email[] = $user->email;
        return true;              
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Works for me, so sorry :( , is silly question but have you check that `$users` is not an empty collection?

Comment: Thanks! that was the problem. I just realized that I did a dd()  in the loop then it stopped on the first iteration. sigh...

Answer (score 0):

What about using the collection helpers like this :

```
$usersWithUniqueMails = $users->unique('email');
$unique_email = $usersWithUniqueMails->pluck('email');
```

Comment: This was my first solution, unfortunately, it doesn't work on an encrypted data. so i had to use filter instead